# Difference of defining and initializing object between mxml and script in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

See following example:

```
Step 1: Var a:A = new A(); // a.o1.label == null, a.o2.label == "o2"
Step 2: a.initialize(); // a.o1.label == “label”
```

A.mxml:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public var o2:Object = {label: "o2"};
            [Bindable] private var _s:String = "o1";
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Object id="o1" label="{_s}"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

So, if I want to use label, I must firstly call initialize()?  But If I coded as var o:Object = {label = _s} in the script, then I can use a.o.label just after Step 1.

Then, It seems the caller should care about the implementation of it's child. Is something wrong here? What's the right solution here? Is it that I shouldn't define/initialize the object in mxml in this case?

I hope if someone can at least provides some documents about this that I can read.

Comment: Google for the "Flex component lifecycle". In a nutshell: you should never call initialize() explicitly. The framework takes care of initializing a component once you add it to the stage.

Comment: @RIAstar Thank you very much. Got one doc and is going to read that.